# Create external account on salesforce EC site

Tags: node.js, salesforce

I have a issuse with my sandbox, on my site I will create a new external profile when login if profile not exsist in customers list. I was debug and check have profile but in  customers list on BM I cant find it. With a same setting and same code on another sandbox it work

I was try to reset sandbox and setup my site but it not work
I want create external profile when login on my site
[This is code create external profile and update data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsEjm.png)
[data debug check have external profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPsOo.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.